# Want to write in stdout after closing the file opened using freopen

Tags: c, stdout, freopen

I'm using `fork()`. However, before executing `fork()`, I open a file (say `a.txt`) using `freopen`  for writing. Now the child process redirects the output of `execlp` to `a.txt`. After terminating the child process, the parent process closes `a.txt`. Now how can the parent process read `a.txt` and show some information in `stdout`?

Answer (score 1):

If the parent process opened the file with `freopen(3)`, then the `rewind(3)` library call can be used to re-wind the stream's pointer to the start of the file, for use with `fread(3)` or `fgets(3)` or whatever API you'd like to use.

Comment: @ sarnold: But I can't write to `stdout`.

Comment: @miraj, aha; I think R.. understood your problem better than I did. Is your trouble writing to the file in the child? Or is the problem reading from the file in the parent?

Comment: The child can write perfectly. The problem is in reading the file and writing to stdout by the parent.

Answer (score 1):

`freopen` does not belong in this code at all. Instead, you should do something like:

```
FILE *tmp = tmpfile();
if (!(pid=fork())) {
    dup2(fileno(tmp), 1);
    close(fileno(tmp));
    execlp(...);
    _exit(1);
}
wait(&status);
/* read from tmp */
```

However it would actually be a lot better to use a **pipe** if possible.